# How to add a custom column to a MvcContrib Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I don't find a method to add a custom column in a MvcContrib Grid. With the old version you could do :

```
column.For("Edit").Do(p => { %>
        <td>
            <a href="/People/Edit/<%= p.Id %>">Edit</a>
        </td>
    %>});
```

But with the latest version, the Do() method disappears...  So now which method use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution :

You have to use the MvcContrib.UI.Grid.ActionSyntax namespace

and it provides you an extension method called "Action".

Here is a simple use :

```
column.For("PDF").Named("PDF").Action(p => { %> 
<td><img src="../Content/Images/pdf.gif" /></td> <% });
```

Comment: .Action has been deprecated in MVC 3 and you should use Column.Custom() instead.

Comment: column.For(string) has also been deprecated, is there another way of doing this?